# Using each iteration of a loop as a variable elsewhere with Python

Tags: python, get

This is a side project I am doing as I am attempting to learn Python.

I am trying to write a python script that will iterate through a date range and use each date that is returned in a GET request URL.

The URL uses a LastModified parameter and limits GET requests to a 24 hour period so I would like to run the GET request for each day from the start date.

Below is what I have currently, the major issue I am having is how to separate the returned dates in a way that I can use each date separately for the GET, the GET will also need to be looped to use each date I suppose.

Any pointer in the right direction would be helpful as I am trying to learn as much as possible.

```
start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)

end_date = datetime.date.today()

delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

while start_date <= end_date:
    last_mod = start_date + delta
    print(last_mod)

    start_date += delta

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

vend_key = 'REDACTED'
user_key = 'REDACTED'
metrc_license = 'A12-0000015-LIC'
base_url = 'https://sandbox-api-ca.metrc.com'
last_mod_date = ''

a = HTTPBasicAuth(vend_key, user_key)


def get(path):
    url = '{}/{}/?licenseNumber={}&lastModifiedStart={}'.format(base_url, path, metrc_license, last_mod_date, )
    print('URL:', url)
    r = requests.get(url, auth=a)
    print("The server response is: ", r.status_code)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    # Would like an elif that is r.status_code is 500 wait _ seconds and try again
    elif r.status_code == 500:
        print("500 error, try again.")
    else:
        print("Error")


print((get('/packages/v1/active')))
```

Here is an example return from the current script, I do not need it to return each date so I can remove the print, but how can I make each loop from the date be its own variable to use in a loop of the GET?

```
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
2020-01-05
2020-01-06
etc...
etc...
etc...
2020-05-24
2020-05-25
2020-05-26
2020-05-27
URL: https://sandbox-api-ca.metrc.com//packages/v1/active/?licenseNumber=A12-0000015-LIC&lastModifiedStart=2020-05-27
The server response is:  200
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's super simple, you need to use use the `while` loop that generates all these dates into your `get()` function. Here is what I mean:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

vend_key = 'REDACTED'
user_key = 'REDACTED'
metrc_license = 'A12-0000015-LIC'
base_url = 'https://sandbox-api-ca.metrc.com'

a = HTTPBasicAuth(vend_key, user_key)


def get(path):
    start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
    end_date = datetime.date.today()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while start_date <= end_date:
        last_mod_date = start_date + delta
        print(last_mod_date)

        start_date += delta
        url = '{}/{}/?licenseNumber={}&lastModifiedStart={}'.format(base_url, path, metrc_license, last_mod_date, )
        print('URL:', url)
        r = requests.get(url, auth=a)
        print("The server response is: ", r.status_code)

        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.json()
        # Would like an elif that is r.status_code is 500 wait _ seconds and try again
        elif r.status_code == 500:
            print("500 error, try again.")
        else:
            print("Error")


print((get('/packages/v1/active')))
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is call your `get` function inside the while loop. First modify the `get` function to take a new parameter `date` and then use this parameter when you build your url.

For instance:

```
def get(path, date):
    url = '{}/{}/?licenseNumber={}&lastModifiedStart={}'.format(base_url, path, metrc_license, date, )
    ...
```

And then call `get` inside the while loop.

```
while start_date <= end_date:
    last_mod = start_date + delta

    get(some_path, last_mod)

    start_date += delta
```

This would make a lot of GET requests in a short period of time, so you might want to be careful not to overload the server with requests.